# shell script to compare files and print formatted output

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to write a shell script which will compare two files, and if there are no differences between then, it will indicate that there was a success, and if there are differences, it will indicate that there was a failure, and print the results. Here's what I have so far:

```
result = $(diff -u file1 file2)

if [ $result = "" ]; then
    echo It works!
else
    echo It does not work
    echo $result
fi
```

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong???

Answer (score 5):

```
result=$(diff -u file1 file2)

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "It works!"
else
    echo "It does not work"
    echo "$result"
fi
```

Suggestions:

- No spaces around "`=`" in the variable assignment for `results`
- Use `$?` status variable after running `diff` instead of the string length of `$result`.
- I'm in the habit of using backticks for command substitution instead of `$()`, but @Dennis Williamson cites some good reasons to use the latter after all.  Thanks Dennis!
- Applied quotes per suggestions in comments.
- Changed "`=`" to "`-eq`" for numeric test.

Comment: I like backticks, too, but this kind of 'matter of taste' thing may get you downvoted by some zealots.

Comment: This is cleaner than my answer, +1

Comment: +1 from me too as it explain more things and look nicer. One problem though, "!" cannot be use without escape or non process wrapping ('').

Comment: Apologies, I reversed the explanation of "`=`" and "`-eq`" in the test syntax.  I have removed my error!

Comment: Don't use backticks. It's not just a matter of taste - nested commands, nested quoting, readability, etc., are all better: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: I looked up the man page for test, and it looks to me as if the "-eq" is for numeric tests... Thanks, but I'm still not sure how to write the part that goes between the [ ] in the If...

Comment: Use "$result" instead of $result.  Applies to original test (which would work with "$result") and answer.

Comment: johnathan, so you're saying it should be: if [ "$?" = 0 ];?

Comment: I think he's saying to use `[ "$result" ]` which returns true when result is non-blank and false when result is blank.  You also have to reverse your then and else clauses.  I just tried this and it works.  But I still prefer to use `$?`.

Comment: And it should not be necessary to put quotes around `$?` because that's a shell builtin variable that is always an integer. Never blank, and never contains spaces.

Answer (score 3):

First, you should wrap strings being compared with quotes.

Second, "!" cannot be use it has another meaning. You can wrap it with single quotes.

So your program will be.

```
result=$(diff -u file1 file2)

if [ "$result" == "" ]; then
    echo 'It works!'
else
    echo It does not work
    echo "$result"
fi
```

Enjoy.

Comment: $result needs to be in double quotes-bash doesn't evaluate stuff in single quotes, so it's actually evaluating the literal string $result here. It works with double quotes, though.

Comment: Right that is my quick type mistake ... I will fix that.

Comment: If you're using Bash or ksh, you can use double brackets [[ ]] and you can often avoid quoting and escaping, plus you get access to more tests including regex matching: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031

Answer (score 0):

Since you need results when you fail, why not simply use 'diff -u file1 file2' in your script? You may not even need a script then. If diff succeeds, nothing will happen, else the diff will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

bash string equivalence is "==". 
-n is non-zero string, -z is zero length string, wrapping in quotes because the command will complain if the output of diff is longer than a single string with "too many arguments".
so

```
if [ -n "$(diff $1 $2)" ]; then
    echo "Different"
fi
```

or

```
if [ -z "$(diff $1 $2)" ]; then
    echo "Same"
fi
```

Comment: But how to output the result when they are different?